# I know it looks like another duplicate but I still need another set of eyes to look at this IEntityChangeTracker exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know this is a widely covered problem here. I delayed even writing this question because of that but I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

The following function is throwing the following exception on the last line. " An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

```
private void addAutoGeneratedStoreCredit(ApplicationDbContext contx, Payment payment)
{
    var autoStoreCredit = new StoreCredit();
    autoStoreCredit.DateTimeLocal = DateTime.Now;
    autoStoreCredit.DateTimeUTC = DateTime.UtcNow;
    autoStoreCredit.UsedAsPayment = false;
    autoStoreCredit.TypeOfStoreCredit = TypeOfStoreCredit.SystemGenerated;
    autoStoreCredit.CustomerID = payment.Transaction.Customer.ID;
    autoStoreCredit.DepartmentID = payment.Transaction.Department.ID;
    autoStoreCredit.EmployeeID = App.CurrentUser.ID;
    autoStoreCredit.Message = string.Format("Auto generated from {0} ID: {1}", payment.StoreCredit.Type, payment.StoreCredit.ID);
    autoStoreCredit.Value = payment.StoreCredit.Change;
    contx.StoreCredits.Add(autoStoreCredit);
}
```

Even if the Payment param is from a different context (which it is not), I am only setting IDs not their corresponding objects.

I have one context which gets passed between functions.

Comment: The only suspect line I can see is `autoStoreCredit.Value = payment.StoreCredit.Change;`. What kind of object is `Value` (or `Change`)?

Comment: They are both decimal

Comment: Any code in `StoreCredit`'s constructor?

Comment: No. No code there.

Comment: What about `TypeOfStoreCredit`? Just an `enum`?

Comment: Yes, that's just an enum. Situation is really weird. It appears that if i pass in the context as a param, I can't add anything directly in it.